# How can I call a function from MainWindow which is present in secondary window in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

[This is the function that is in secondary window named **hello**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXF3t.png)

```
 void hello::save()
{
    QString file_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Open the file","X://");
    QFile file(file_name);
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","File not Open");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&file);
    QString text = ui->textEdit_sec->toPlainText();
   out<<text;
   file.flush();
   file.close();

}
```

[I need that function here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgBgW.png)

```
 void MainWindow::on_actionsavew_triggered()
{


}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text and format it with the { } button instead of images.

Comment: yes now please look at it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a static function in a common include file:

```
 void saveStatic(QWidget* parent, const QString& text)
{
    QString file_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(parent,"Open the file","X://");
    QFile file(file_name);
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","File not Open");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&file);
    QString text =
   out<<text;
   file.flush();
   file.close();

}
```

and call it from both of the function like this:

```
 void MainWindow::on_actionsavew_triggered()
{
 saveStatic(this, ui->textEdit_sec->toPlainText());
}
```

and

```
void hello::save()
{
    saveStatic(this, ui->textEdit_sec->toPlainText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt way of doing this is to use signal and slots. Your save function should be your slot and the on_... functions should call a signal. You the connect the two with QObject::connect